# If I use locks, can my algorithm still be lock-free?

Tags: multithreading

A common definition of lock-free is that at least one process makes progress. <sup>1</sup>

If I have a simple data structure such as a queue, protected by a lock, then one process can always make progress, as one process can acquire the lock, do what it wants, and release it.

So does it meet the definition of lock-free?

---

<sup>1</sup> See eg M. Herlihy, V. Luchangco, and M. Moir. Obstruction-free synchronization: Double-ended queues as an example. In Distributed Computing, 2003. "It is lock-free if it ensures only that some thread always makes progress".

Comment: I've always understood "lock free" to describe a data structure and set of algorithms that don't use locks, just a small defined set of atomic memory operations.  E.g. http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/writing-lock-free-code-a-corrected-queue/210604448

Answer (score 16):

That's no definition for lock-free.

If you can guarantee progress then you have *deadlock-free*, and if you have the eventual completion of every request, then you have *starvation-free*, but not lock-free.

I question whether your simple example actually provides this anyway.  You need lock hierarchies and so on to actually make progress guarantees when multiple locks are involved.

Comment: I'm using the definition from M. Herlihy. A methodology for implementing highly concurrent data objects. Transactions on Program- ming Languages and Systems, 1993. "The lock-free condition guarantees that some process will always make progress despite arbitrary halting failures or delays by other processes"

Comment: @Joe: That isn't a definition, it describes an implication.  Beware the logic fallacy of the inverse.

Comment: Could also quote M. Herlihy, V. Luchangco, and M. Moir. Obstruction-free synchronization: Double-ended queues as an example. In Distributed Computing, 2003. "It is lock-free if it ensures only that some thread always makes progress".

Comment: there is also starvation free which is more specific than deadlock free (every process gets to go no matter what other processes do) note that CaS loops (based on atomic primitives) aren't

Comment: Yeah, I know the paper is about obstruction-free... but in the course of explaining it they give definitions for wait free and lock free. Did you actually read the paper or just assume from the title? The quote very clearly says "It is LOCK-FREE if...". Wait and lock free have evolved somewhat, so there is no authoritative single definition from when it was first mentioned, but you can't really beat Herlihy for wait, lock and obstruction free.

Comment: @Joe: If the rest of the world calls that property *deadlock-free*, then I'm going to use that term.  No, your simple example is not deadlock-free.  In order to guarantee that something is deadlock-free, you not only need synchronization, but a guarantee that no thread performs any blocking operation while holding the lock.  "do what it wants" is extremely vague and doesn't appear to provide this guarantee.

Comment: It sounds like he's just describing a single lock.

Comment: @Panzercrisis: So you think it is "Do what it wants, excluding acquiring any other lock"?  That still doesn't meet any of the progress conditions, because you could begin waiting for I/O or any other condition that needs to be triggered by another thread waiting for the lock you are holding.  "Do what you want" while holding a lock is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @BenVoigt I see.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Instead of saying "Excluding acquiring any other lock" should more accurately be written as "Excluding any operation whose completion might require actions by any other thread that can't be relied upon to perform it in bounded time."

Comment: @supercat: That's pretty much [what I said](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/141271/if-i-use-locks-can-my-algorithm-still-be-lock-free/141272?noredirect=1#comment266543_141272).

Comment: OP's topic is a synchronized queue and we can imagine pretty clearly what its enqueue and dequeue methods do while holding a lock. They don't cede control to alien code and they don't issue HTTP requests. So the OP asked whether methods with such specific implementations can be called "lock-free". Given that "an infinite number of times _some_ thread can complete it method invocation".

Answer (score 11):

I've studied The Art of Multiprocessor Programming<sup>1</sup> and their text is lacking in clarity, just like the book you refer to. Here are some quotes from TAMPP:

#### Quote 1 (Definition of lock-free)

> A method is lock-free if it guarantees that infinitely often some method call finishes in a finite number of steps.

#### Quote 2 (Definition of nonblocking)

> a pending invocation of a total method is never required to wait for another pending invocation to complete.

#### Quote 3 (claim that lock-free is nonblocking)

> The wait-free and lock-free nonblocking progress conditions guarantee that the computation as a whole makes progress, independently of how the system schedules threads.

The problem is that the claim in Quote 3 does not obviously follow from the definition in Quote 1. As already mentioned, a synchronized queue seems to satisfy Quote 1: infinitely often some method will successfully acquire the lock and complete.

Note specifically the quite vague phrase in Quote 3: "independently of how the system schedules threads". This is not preceded by any kind of a formal description of the "thread-scheduling system", so we are left to reconstruct its properties based on our preconceptions on what the definitions *should* mean:

1. the system always executes instructions of *some* thread;
2. it may never execute instructions of any *given* thread;
3. *all* the threads are invoking the method under consideration.

On such a system, a blocking method cannot be lock-free: if the thread holding the lock is never again scheduled for execution, there will be no other thread which can complete its method invocation in a finite number of steps, yet there will be some threads that are executing steps of the method. For a more realistic system, one which does guarantee to give CPU time to each thread eventually, the definition must explicitly include the nonblocking property:

#### Corrected definition of lock-free

> A method is lock-free if it is non-blocking and, additionally, guarantees that infinitely often some method call finishes in a finite number of steps.

<sup>1</sup> Maurice Herlihy, Nir Shavit, The Art of Multiprocessor Programming, Elsevier 2008, pp. 58-60

Comment: The wording of quote 1 is really strange. What do they mean by "infinitely often"? Obviously something different than "always", so it is ok that the method does never return in "some" cases?

Comment: Yes, imprecise language abounds. What's "often" anyway? I think they mean "in an infinite execution history, this particular event occurs infinitely many times".

Answer (score 5):

Terminology isn't always consistent, but I think what's important is to ask the following questions about a proposed algorithm or system:

1. Is there any sequence of events where threads could become stuck waiting for each other even if all threads were allowed all CPU time they could use [if so, it's not deadlock free]

   If one thread were blocked for an arbitrary long time, could that stall other threads or impair system operation for an arbitrarily long time [if so, it's not non-blocking].

   Is there some at-least-theoretically possible combination of thread scheduling which could cause all threads to repeatedly retry the same operations while invalidating each others' work, without anyone making progress [if so, it's not lock-free]

   If some threads are given sufficiently CPU time relative to another, could they force the latter thread to keep retrying its operations indefinitely [if so, it's not wait-free].

Much of the significance of lock-free algorithms isn't that they're faster than non-lock-free algorithms, but rather the fact that they aren't prone to dying if a thread gets waylaid [note that such a guarantee merely requires that algorithms be non-blocking, but all lock-free algorithms are].  It's possible for a lock-free algorithm to use locks, but only if lock-acquisition attempts include timeouts along with algorithms to ensure that it will always be possible for someone to make progress (for example, an algorithm could use a `CompareExchange` loop as its primary arbitration method, but use locks to arbitrate access when contention seems high; if a lock seems to be held for excessively long, other threads could decide to abandon efforts to use that lock and instead create a new one.  Note that because consistency is ensured via `CompareExchange`, having customers abandon the lock wouldn't jeopardize system consistency, though it may mean that code which had been holding the old lock won't get any work done until it too abandons the old lock and gets in line for the new one.

Comment: This is different from standard terminology: your 2. refers to the standard meaning of non-blocking whereas 3. refers to lock freedom.

Comment: I've seen inconsistent terminology usages, and I don't know of an "official" standard.  What's most important is that there are different guarantees an algorithm may be able to offer, and it's important to use an algorithm which offers guarantees sufficient to meet application requirements.  Many papers only cover some of the guarantees above, but there are cases where each may be be able to satisfy application requirements more easily than any other guarantees which would meet requirements.

Comment: I think there's a consensus that the terminology presented in The Art of Multiprocessor Programming is "standard".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I'll edit the post to fit that then.  Do you like the new version?.

Comment: Cool, very nice.

Answer (score 4):

You have to look at the "definition" you quote in [context](http://www.scribd.com/doc/62215134/10-1-1-83-7992-1):

> The traditional way to implement shared data structures is to use
>   mutual exclusion (locks) to ensure that concurrent operations do not
>   interfere with one another. Locking has a number of disadvantages with
>   respect to software engineering,fault-tolerance, and scalability (see
>   [8]). In response,researchers have investigated a variety of
>   **alternative synchronization techniques that do not employ mutual
>   exclusion**. A synchronization technique is wait-free if it ensures that
>   every thread will continue to make progress in the face of arbitrary
>   delay (or even failure) of other threads. It is lock-free if it
>   ensures only that some thread always makes progress.

You're using locks for mutual exclusion, thus it's not a lock-free technique they are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

> If I use locks, can my algorithm still be lock-free?

It could be, but it depends on the algorithm.

> If I have a simple data structure such as a queue, protected by a lock, then one process can always make progress, as one process can acquire the lock, do what it wants, and release it.
>
> So does it meet the definition of lock-free?

Note *per se*.

If the *"do what it wants"* step does not involve acquiring any other locks, and it is guaranteed to complete in a finite time, then this particular part of your algorithm will be deadlock free.

However, if those preconditions are not satisfied, there is at least the potential for deadlocks ...

Comment: After some study of the text in The Art of Multiprocessor Programming I've come to the conclusion that mutexes definitely invalidate the definition of lock-free, when the definition is correctly spelled out. I've added an answer to this page to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

The example you give is not lock-free for the following reason.

Support one thread acquires the lock, and the OS scheduler suspended the thread for a infinite lone period, then all of the thread cannot make progress because no can can acquire the lock that is acquired by the suspended thread.

Generally speaking, algorithms that use locks are not lock-free.

Note that deadlock-free and lock-free are two different concepts. deadlock-free means there is no possibility for deadlock, but there could be livelock which can prevent the whole system from making progress. Lock-freedom is stronger than that because it means some threads in the system always makes progress with finite number of steps.

Comment: Look at a more careful definition on Wikipedia: "An algorithm is lock-free if it satisfies that when the program threads are run sufficiently long at least one of the threads makes progress." This excludes the case of halting threads. Also progress under halting is covered by _obstruction freedom_, not _lock freedom_.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Your comment does not make sense at all. Lock-freedom covers obstruction-freedom. Anything that is lock-free must be obstruction-free. And the definition you gave does not exclude halting threads.

Comment: Please take care to distinguish "making sense" from "being correct". My comment is incorrect, as can be seen from my subsequent answer. But the Wikipedia definition is also wrong or at least ambiguous.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Since you admit that your comment is not correct, you should remove it to avoid confusing other readers. Wikipedia is often incorrect or ambiguous. You should find subtle definitions like "lock-freedom" in academic papers such as https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/papers/2006_PPoPP_synch_queues.pdf (the definition of lock-free is in section 2.1)

Comment: Yes, including the nonblocking property as a part of the definition of lock-freedom is one way to do it. That was stated in an earlier revision of my answer.

Comment: @Chaoran I'm not sure that lock-free implies obstruction-free
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4446734/8346628